# JavaScript inheritance and constructors

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I'm trying to understand inheritance in JavaScript. I'm using prototype to link a child class to it's parent. But as soon as I'm defining the relationship the constructor of the parent class starts running.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Person ()
        {
            window.alert('We\'ve got a new person!');
        }

        function King ()
        {
            window.alert('We\'ve got a new king!');
        }

        King.prototype = new Person();

        //King.prototype.constructor = King;
        //var erik = new King();
    </script>
```

What's the correct way of using inheritance in JavaScript?

The tutorial that started the confusion: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: Check http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/ as well

Comment: _"But as soon as I'm defining the relationship the constructor of the parent class starts running."_ Well, what do you expect to happen when you write `new Person()`? I don't see a problem here. `[works-as-designed]`

Comment: For future readers; the following text made me understand the idea behind inheritance in JavaScript:
---
Even though it was used as a prototype, the parent object can be still manipulated as a regular object. This is the main difference of a prototype from a class.
---   
All Objects in JavaScript can be modified during the runtime. Since prototype objects are also regular objects, we can modify them too. However, when you modify a prototype object its changes are reflected to all its descended objects too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Javascript is a prototyped language and doesn't really support inheritance in that way. It's objects are loose types that can be extended with extra functions and properties on the fly.

So what you actually do, is create an `instance` of Person, which can then be extended with extra methods.

The tuturial states this:

> In JavaScript you do this by assigning an instance of the parent class
>   to the child class, and then specializing it.

It is rather confusing if you are used to real (well, class based) OO.

Comment: very confusing :s but I needed to double check here. Was hard to image that this is done by design...

Comment: @Golez -- There are those who would say that Javascript/Scheme is the *real* OO, and that the class-based stuff is just a pale copy.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I know. I should have put 'real' in quotes or something. I'm not strongly choosing sides in that discussion, at least not here. ;)